# Access static property from defaults

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following model:

```
    var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults: {
                status:     this.constructor.status.OFFLINE,
            },
        },
        {
            status:   {
                OFFLINE: 0,
                ONLINE:  1,
                BUSY:    2,
                AWAY:    3,
            },
        }
    );
```

I also tried:

```
status:     User.status.OFFLINE
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.constructor.status.OFFLINE')
```

or this:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'User.status')
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Not sure if you realize but you are passing in a second object to your User model which contains a property status that is a second object (in other words status is not a propery of User. but rather of an object passed in). Aside from that I haven't seen any example of creating a Model in this way (by passing in a second object), where did you take that from?

Comment: You do realise you have excess commas in your code which means that your code is simply discarded in IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to reference a static property that is not defined at the moment you create your User model.

Either define your defaults as a function

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() {
        return {status: User.status.OFFLINE}
    }
}, {
    status:   {
        OFFLINE: 0,
        ONLINE:  1,
        BUSY:    2,
        AWAY:    3
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/6XuC8/

or define first your static properties and then extend User.prototype to add your defaults:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({}, {
    status:   {
        OFFLINE: 0,
        ONLINE:  1,
        BUSY:    2,
        AWAY:    3
    }
});

_.extend(User.prototype, {
    defaults: {
        status: User.status.OFFLINE
    }
});

var u = new User();
console.log(u.get('status'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/6XuC8/2/